# Substituir última vírgula de uma string no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, stored-procedures, substring

Possuo duas querys no sql que é o seguinte:

```
    SELECT A.*, B.NOME, C.LAVADO, C.DELEUCO, C.IRRADIADO, C.REFRAC, C.INATIVADO 
INTO #MAPA_TRANSFUSIONAL 
FROM MAPA_TRANSFUSIONAL A    
        INNER JOIN TUSUARIO B ON A.COD_USU = B.COD_USU 
        INNER JOIN BOLSA C ON A.NR_DOAC = C.NR_DOAC AND A.COD_HEMO = C.COD_HEMO
WHERE A.COD_REGISTRO = '0009625'   
AND A.TIPO_PACIENTE = 'I'    
AND A.COD_USU = B.COD_USU     
AND ((ISNULL('2010-01-01','') = '' AND ISNULL('2010-12-31','') = '') OR A.DTHR_MOV BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-12-31')    
AND A.COD_COMP = C.COD_COMP
ORDER BY A.DTHR_MOV    

CREATE TABLE #PROCEDIMENTO (DTH_PROCEDIMENTO CHAR(16), NOM_USUARIO CHAR(50), TIP_PROCEDIMENTO CHAR(30), DES_PROCEDIMENTO VARCHAR(MAX), OBS2 VARCHAR(MAX),   
                            COD_HEMO CHAR(8),NR_DOAC INT, COD_COMP CHAR(4), SEQ_BOLSA SMALLINT, REG SMALLINT,  MATRIC INT, DTH_PROCEDIMENTO2 SMALLDATETIME, 
                            TIP_PROCEDIMENTO2 CHAR(30), ORDEM_CHAVE SMALLINT, COD_INST CHAR(8),    
                            COD_USU_PROVA SMALLINT, COMPATIVEL_PROVA CHAR, HEMOLISE_PROVA CHAR, NUM_PROVA INT, NUM_DOC_EXP INT, 
                            COD_PROCEDIMENTO INT, NUM_ESTUDO CHAR(6), COD_REGISTRO CHAR(7), COD_USU SMALLINT,   
       TIPO_PACIENTE CHAR, OBS TEXT ) 

INSERT INTO #PROCEDIMENTO( DTH_PROCEDIMENTO2, NOM_USUARIO, COD_INST, TIP_PROCEDIMENTO, TIP_PROCEDIMENTO2, COD_PROCEDIMENTO, COD_HEMO, NR_DOAC, COD_COMP, SEQ_BOLSA,  DES_PROCEDIMENTO )    
SELECT  DTHR_MOV, NOME, COD_INST, 'Transfusão', 'Transfusão', 10, COD_HEMO, NR_DOAC, COD_COMP, SEQ_BOLSA,      
        'Bolsa: '+ RTRIM(LTRIM(COD_HEMO)) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),NR_DOAC) +' - '+ RTRIM(LTRIM(COD_COMP)) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),SEQ_BOLSA)+
        CASE WHEN  LAVADO <> 'N' AND LAVADO IS NOT NULL  THEN ', LAV' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN DELEUCO <> 'N' AND DELEUCO IS NOT NULL THEN ', DEL' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN IRRADIADO <> 'N' AND IRRADIADO IS NOT NULL THEN ', IRR' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN REFRAC <> 'N' AND REFRAC IS NOT NULL THEN ', REF' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN INATIVADO <> 'N' AND INATIVADO IS NOT NULL THEN ', INA' ELSE '' END
FROM #MAPA_TRANSFUSIONAL
```

Como o resultado de DELEUCO, LAVADO, IRRADIADO, REFRAC E INATIVADO são variáveis, preciso incluir um 'e' ao invés da última vírgula caso tenha 2 ou mais procedimentos (DELEUCO, LAVADO, IRRADIADO, REFRAC E INATIVADO).

Tentei o substring() e o charindex() mas ainda não consegui o resultado esperado.

Comment: uma alternativa seria utilizar a função Reverse antes das funções citadas para obter a string em ordem reversa e trocar a primeira vírgula por 'E'  em vez da última, e depois utilizar a Reverse novamente para voltar a string a ordem original

Comment: olá, pode me dizer atraves de um exemplo? Tentei usar também o reverse mas acho que estou fazendo algo errado.

Answer (score -2):

Talvez isso aqui ajude.
Como o imex sugeriu ai acima. A função reverse ajuda bem.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.substitui_ultima_virgula(
-- Sua string inicial
@string NVARCHAR(MAX),
-- Caractere que voce quer usar para substituir a ultima virgula
@char NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @resposta NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @resposta = STUFF(@string, LEN(@string) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@string)) + 1, 1, @char)
    -- Retorno da sua string com a ultima virgula substituida
    RETURN @resposta;
END;

-- Exemplo para chamada da funcao
SELECT dbo.substitui_ultima_virgula('quero, trocar, a, ultima, virgula por E', 'E')
```